# My place of birth does not match my passport

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, applications, yemeni-citizens

I was born in America, but I did not obtain American citizenship because my parents at that time were diplomatic envoys. In general, I traveled as a tourist to America in 2006 with a foreign diplomatic passport (noting that the date and place of my birth in the passport is completely different from my American birth certificate) and there I applied to obtain American citizenship and then left everything and went back to my country. Now I want to go tourism to America for two months. Is it better to apply for travel with the same old diplomatic passport, or to apply with a normal passport? Do I change my data in the passport according to the US birth certificate, or do I keep it as it is?

Comment: Depending on the jurisdiction, diplomatic passports may only be used when on a diplomatic mission. A host country is **not** required to grant any form of immunity when the passport holder is not on a reconized diplomatic mission. The question arises why the diplomatic passport has an incorrect date and place of birth.

Comment: Is your diplomatic passport still valid? What is your other citizenship? Why are the details different to your birth certificate?

Comment: How can date and and place of birth be different between the certificates? You have only been born once, so only one can be correct. You should try to get the wrong one fixed.

Comment: Also Id check into whether you are even eligible for US citizenship based on being born in the US, given there are exemptions around diplomatic staffs children being eligible…

Comment: I also believe that some countries operate with the quirk that children born abroad by parents in diplomatic duty are not legally considered to be born abroad. That *may* be the reason why the true place of birth differs from offical records and what's stated in a passport.

Comment: True, and that is why when I traveled to America previously, I applied for a tourist visa with my diplomatic passport that I acquired from my father because of his work at the time. I am from an Arab country called Yemen, and here administratively, the difference in data does not matter. It was my father who did it.

Comment: My diplomatic passport expired a long time ago. My father is deceased, and he is the one who acquired the diplomatic passport through him. However, I can extend the validity of the passport.
My current nationality is "Yemeni".

Comment: What concerns me now... Do I fill out the information on the tourist visa form according to the data of the Yemeni passport that I have or according to my American birth certificate? (Both are different from the other).
Or I amend the passport data before submitting, knowing that I traveled to America previously and applied for a green card, and then left everything, meaning that my real information they have.

Comment: @Zezo you need an immigration lawyer, not this website.

Comment: To expand on Moo's comment: by previously applying for a visa using your Yemeni diplomatic passport, you provided untrue data to USCIS. _USCIS retains this information_. If you file another application, the earlier application will be compared with the new one. Because the info is different. USCIS will determine either that you lied on your earlier application, or that you're lying in your current application. This will result in a denial, and could also result in a ban for deception. This is dangerous ground. You need help from a US immigration attorney **before** taking any action.

Comment: Please **edit** your question to include the additional background information you have mentioned in a couple of comments. Why did you apply for a green card and then leave without waiting to get one? That application *will be on record*, further complicating your situation given the US stance on presumed immigrant intent related to visitor visas

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica giving the place of birth as stated in a foreign passport when that place of birth is the place legally considered to be correct in foreign law can hardly be considered a "lie."

Comment: @phoog I took the OP's statement (in one of the questions or comments) that the information about place and date of birth in the diplomatic passport was different from the same information as stated by the OP in his subsequent visa application. Inconsistent information will certainly be a red flag.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica absolutely a red flag, yes.  But if the discrepancy can be explained as a byproduct of the other country's normal administrative practice, there shouldn't be any finding of misrepresentation.  That still doesn't answer the question of how to complete the visa application or precisely how to explain the discrepancy, of course.  If it's possible to get a Yemeni passport with the US place of birth that would likely be the easiest solution.

Comment: How will the match be done if I edit the place and date of birth and some letters in the name? How will they know that it was I who traveled to them earlier? And when will they know? At the consulate or at the border customs? Although it is good that I will modify the data on the passport, this is as I expect positive, where will the real data be?

Answer (score 1):

You should apply for a normal Yeman passport that is factually correct in every way

- especially the correct place of birth

> ... I applied to obtain American citizenship and then left everything and went back to my country

Did you 'apply' for **or** did you 'claim' US citizenship based on on your birth certificate?

More **importantly**, did you inform them that your parents, at the time of your birth, had a diplomatic status (i.e. were not 'subject to the jurisdiction of the United States')?

- not doing this would be considered **deception**

  - for which you then have problems that may be difficult to resolve

> I traveled as a tourist to America in 2006 with a foreign diplomatic passport (noting that the date and place of my birth in the passport is completely different from my American birth certificate)

Were you a minor at the time when the passport was issued and traveled?

Collect proof that your father (I assume) was actually **officialy** appointed as a diplomat to the United States and accepted as such by the United States (the US State Department should have records of this, since they must accept such appointments).

If you have the passports they used at the time of your birth (showing under what conditions they were admitted to the United States), that will be very helpfull.

If your father was only **visiting** the United States, possibly **without** a diplomatic visa in his diplomatic passport, then it *may very well be* that they were 'subject to the jurisdiction of the United States' during that visit.
This **must** be properly documented.

---

With this information (where required with translations), have a **qualified**<sup>1)</sup> lawyer compile a letter that would accompany a visa application.

Goal of this letter would be to clarify the situation in a manor that **all** of the more  complicated aspects are clear<sup>2)</sup>.

Due to the present situation in Yemen, US documents should preferably be used<sup>2)</sup> where practical.

<sup>1): who understands **exactly** when a person is 'subject to the jurisdiction of the United States' or not</sup>
<sup>2): if your qualified lawyer doesn't understand the reason why, **get another lawyer**!</sup>

Comment: I just want to visit America for two months and go back to my children. I want the easiest, safest and fastest way to get a visa.

Comment: @Zezo Your commnt contains information that is not exactly what I understand under 'factually correct in every way'. **Deception** leads to bans. Follow the advise given the answer.