# Information Required for DS 160 Form

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, applications

I want to apply for a B2 tourist visa to USA for the second time after 15 years and I have some questions
1- The date and place of my birth in the certificate is different from it in the passport (for reasons that are difficult to explain here), so what should I write exactly in the DS 160 form?
Notes:-

- My first visit, i wrote the information according to the passport, which is contrary to the birth certificate.
- My real information is with USCIS, since I applied for green card there, but I traveled and left everything.
- The procedures for modifying passport data are long and complex.
  I am worried about all this as it will increase the complications of visa approval What do I do?

And if approved, will the visa information be according to the passport or Form 160?

Comment: “I am worried about this. What do I do?” The answer is *not* to ask a bunch of internet strangers essentially the same question three times. Your situation is complex, you need expert advice from a suitably-qualified and experienced immigration lawyer

Comment: Can you direct me to the appropriate lawyer or website for my case?

Answer (score 3):

This is now the third time you have asked essentially the same question: how to apply for a visa to visit the US. The previous questions are [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/173536/my-place-of-birth-does-not-match-my-passport) and [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/173559/what-happens-if-my-data-in-the-ds-160-form-is-different). Each question has generated many suggestions and comments and requests for clarification. Some factual questions about your situation and history remain unanswered.

Your situation is complex and unusual. None of us has experienced what you are experiencing. We are not lawyers who practice immigration law. Given the challenges in your matter and the serious consequences that might occur, relying on the advice of anonymous strangers on the internet is not a prudent course of action.

I agree with the suggestion that you should consult a US attorney who regularly practices in the field of US immigration law.

Comment: Yes... Thankyou

Comment: Can you direct me to the appropriate lawyer or website for my case?

Comment: This is a different question, and this site is one question at a time. Please ask as a separate question.